# Jquery.ajax to retrieve data from database

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating MVC3 Site and using pagination (using PagedList;) in that to display bunch of data. I have a stored procedure which gets more than 2000 rows per call.

I have used AJAX with JQUERY to retrieve data (`$.ajax` call in jquery) and doing pagination on retrieved data in controller. So I am getting back 2000 data rows from a stored procedure and doing pagination on them in the controller and show 10 rows of data. But when I click on "Next" / "previous" links, controller calls the same stored procedure again and retrieves another 2000 rows and in controller based on pagenumber it displays data. So every time it fetches 2000 rows.

I am not using any wrapper class here. Calling stored procedure directly from controller.

Thanks.

Comment: I am using database first approach here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to modify the stored procedure so that it takes the current page number and the number of records to return as parameters. This way the pagination will be done directly on the SQL Server which is the only correct way to do pagination if you are concerned about efficiency as it avoids you from fetching all the records from the database and slicing them on the client.

Comment: I thought of that approach but then whats the use of AJAX ? I think AJAX does not refresh the page and improve performance.. So AJAX does not improve performance in terms of fetching data. Is there any way so that I can store that data temporarily and play around with it in controller to get next set of data using ajax?

Comment: Doing that would mean that the Controller is "stateful" which is something in general you want to avoid. There is no magic in Ajax except the fact that allows for asyncronous calls to a server while keeping the interface (hopefully) responsive. You will need to develop around your pagination code, and the SQL server solution in the answer is the correct way of doing it.